# Sampling using an id variable

Tags: r, sampling

I know how to do ordinary random sampling using R:

```
mysample <- mydata[sample(1:nrow(mydata), 100),]
```

However, I want to sample by id variables. Let me explain - my dataset looks like this:

```
id var1 var2 ...
1  5.1  1.2
1  4.7  0.9
2  3.3  1.6
3  3.4  5.7
4  7.9  1.3
```

Now, I want to take a random sample of, say, 2, by id numbers. Let's say the random sample yields id 1 and 4, then my sample would look like this:

```
id var1 var2 ...
1  5.1  1.2
1  4.7  0.9
4  7.9  1.3
```

In other words, I'm sampling 2 id numbers, but I'm actually getting 3 cases.

How can I accomplish this in R?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your data:

```
mydata <- read.table(text = "id var1 var2 
1  5.1  1.2
1  4.7  0.9
2  3.3  1.6
3  3.4  5.7
4  7.9  1.3", header = TRUE)
```

Sample two `id` values:

```
set.seed(1)
ids <- sample(unique(mydata$id), 2) # important: the UNIQUE id numbers
# [1] 2 4
```

Extract subset:

```
mydata[mydata$id %in% ids, ]
#   id var1 var2
# 3  2  3.3  1.6
# 5  4  7.9  1.3
```